# Issue performing JNDI lookup of JMS queue configured in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jndi

I am having one issue looking up a JMS queue configured in JBoss configured in a VM. Initially I thought it was an issue by connecting to it remotely. When I got access to VM, I executed the sample JMS Java client program inside the VM, and still I get the same error that I have mentioned below.

I tried setting up SSL configurations as mentioned in JBoss documentation to connect to the queue in local and it works fine. Only difference that I observed is in local the JBoss uses Oracle JDK and in VM it uses Open JDK.

Normal JMS lookup with the below SSL property configured. the same configuration is done in the standalone.xml by providing the truststore file name and password.

```
sslProperty.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",keystoreFile);
sslProperty.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",password);
```

Error obtained from server log.

```
Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [https-remoting://ipAddress:443 (org.xnio.http.UpgradeFailedException: Invalid response code 200)]
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:244)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:149)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:130)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
      at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
      at com.test.jms.JBoss7JmsClient.sendMessage(JBoss7JmsClient.java:47)
      at com.test.jms.JBoss7JmsClient.main(JBoss7JmsClient.java:27)
```

Comment: The exception you pasted has nothing to with JMS, per se. The exception is being thrown by the JNDI implementation during a JNDI lookup. JNDI and JMS are 100% independent specifications and implementations. Please provide the code from your `JBoss7JmsClient`. Also, the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` properties are *system* properties and should be set accordingly. Also, please include your `standalone.xml` as well.

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes javax.net.ssl.trustStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword properties are set as System properties. In standalone.xml after adding the following under this remoting 3:0 subsystem   
<http-connector name="https-remoting-connector" connector-ref="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" sasl-protocol="remote"/> the issue of connecting to the jms queue with SSL configured is resolved.